# Swift 3 send json request I want to use this function so I have difficulties to understand

Tags: json, swift3

I found this function to send JSon request and receive the answer

```
func sendRequest(urlString: String, method: String, completion: @escaping (_ dictionary: NSDictionary?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:urlString)!)
    request.httpMethod = method
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
            // make error here and then
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            do {
                let jsonDictionary:NSDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: Any] as NSDictionary

                completion(jsonDictionary, nil)

            } catch {
                completion(nil, error)
            }
        }

    }

    task.resume()
}
}
```

I need to understand how to call this function correctly. I know urlString and method parameters so the completion and how to return the answer to use it after calling this function.

Comment: you want a GET request to recieve JSON data?

Comment: no ino I need to send it to POST method so I let the possibility to send it in GET if I need